# Compare tuples with elements not in order

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a two dicts that I'm converting bot to tuples . Both dict contain the same elements, but they are not generated using the same logic .

For example let's say I have a tuple like this :

```
(('a',5),('n',4),('c',8))
```

And the 2nd tuple is like that :

```
(('c',8),('n',4),('a',5))
```

Their original dicts is like that (probably, I can't know how will the elements be ordered in the dict however they are generated from two dicts that contains the same elements (no more, no less) :

```
{'a':5,'c': 8,'n':4}
```

For a human being both tuples are similar, but for a computer they are not .

How can I go with checking if two tuples are similar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort both the `tuple` and compare them. For example:

```
>>> tuple_1 = (('a',5),('n',4),('c',8))
>>> tuple_2 = (('c',8),('n',4),('a',5))

# Non-sorted --> unequal; issue you are currently facing
>>> tuple_1 == tuple_2
False

# comparing sorted tuples -- equal 
>>> sorted(tuple_1) == sorted(tuple_2)
True
```

If the elements of both the tuples are *unique*, you may also compare them via using `set` as:

```
>>> set(tuple_1) == set(tuple_2)
True
```

---

As a side note, you do not have to convert the `dict` to `tuple` in order to compare the content of dictionaries. You may directly compare the `dict` objects as:

```
>>> {1: 2, 3: 4} == {3: 4, 1: 2}
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also convert the tuples to a `dict` and then compare them.

Not sure if this is faster/slower/the same as sorting them.

```
dict(t1) == dict(t2)
```

Comment: It will be faster than `sorted` since the complexity for creating a dict from tuple will be  `N`. But this will fail if two elements in the tuple have same object at index 0. But again, since the OP is creating the `tuple` from `dict`, it will suffice his requirement. But won't be applicable for others looking for comparing tuples in generalized way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def similarTuple(a,b):
    h = {}
    for e in a:
        h[e] = True
    for e in b:
        if e not in h:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a set of both tuples and compare those:

```
a = (('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2))
b = (('b', 1), ('a', 0), ('c', 2))
set(a) == set(b)
```

Comment: won't work if there are more than 1 occurrence of the same tuple.

Answer (score 0):

trying for a one liner, exploring getting a bool result from list comprehensions

not efficient, possibly amusing

```
def SameElementsP(a,b):
    return not ( [1 for e in a if e not in b] or [1 for e in b if e not in a] )
```